# How to take different string inputs for new nodes in a linked list?

Tags: string, pointers, linked-list

```cpp
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

struct node
{
    char *s;
    struct node *next;
};
 
struct node* getstring(struct node *tail)
{   
    struct node *ptr = (struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node*));
    printf("Enter the string:");
    scanf("%2s",ptr->s);
    ptr->next = NULL;
    tail->next = ptr;
    tail = ptr;
    return tail;
}

int main()
{
    struct node *head = malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    head->s = "Operating system";
    head->next = NULL;

    struct node *tail;
    tail = head;

    tail = allocate(tail);
    tail = allocate(tail);
    
    struct node *temp = head;
    while(temp!=NULL)
    {  
        printf("%20s\n",temp->s);
        temp = temp->next;
    }
}
```

In the above code the `getstring()` function will insert a new node at the end of the linked list and take user input and assign it to the char pointer.

But after taking the input multiple times (in this case two times) it assigns the most recent string to every node, not to the particular node. how do I resolve this issue?

Comment: You will get better answers when you add the most important tag: the language.

Answer (score 0):

There are several issues, but the main one is that `ptr->s` is a char-pointer without any space allocated for what it points to.

So you should allocate memory for it. As you seem to be reading 2 characters ("%2s"), allocate enough memory as follows, before executing `scanf`:

```
ptr->s = (char*) malloc(sizeof(char)*3);
```

Other remarks:

- Your code doesn't call `getstring`, but `allocate`. So fix those two lines to call `getstring`
- `struct node *ptr = (struct node*) malloc(sizeof(struct node*))` is not allocating the right size of memory, since you take the size of the *pointer*, not the struct. So remove that last asterisk:

  ```
  struct node *ptr = (struct node*) malloc(sizeof(struct node));
  ```
- You should explicitly cast in the following lines:

  ```
  struct node *head = (struct node*) malloc(sizeof(struct node));
  head->s = (char*) "Operating system";
  ```
- It is better practice to free any memory allocated with `malloc` before finishing